# Cannot get started with learning SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013

I am new to SharePoint in general and I am going to start a new SharePoint 2013 project. I have registered with plursight training and I have attended some online sessions with them in addition I have read some materials on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/fp123633.aspx. But till now I am unable to figure out how to link the SharePoint components together especially for those which are required to build an interactive knowledge based library for my company.

As all the training courses are talking about SharePoint 2013 as concepts and features with minimal demos showing how these components work together on a live environment, or to implement a full business scenario even if it is a simple scenario.

I think when learning any new technology , it is better to see how to build a simple application from A-Z which can help in understanding the whole picture for the technology. For example when I first learn asp.net mvc I have read how to build an application named NerdDinner (which is simple mvc application) but it was a solid starting point to understand MVC details and more advance functionalities.

So from where I can find demos which show how to build a simple SharePoint 2013 applications, bearing in mind that what I am trying to achieve in SharePoint 2013 (at least for the current stage) are :-

1. To build a knowledge library categorizing all our company procedures, manuals, technical material, policies, etc.
2. Enable employees to write the above contents and publish them, so they can be view, edited, updated, delete by specific users.
3. To have some workflows on certain documents, so that they will not be available to employees until they went through predefined approval steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are taking SharePoint bit too easy here, I met people who are working on SharePoint for years and years but still there are area's in SharePoint they got no clue about or have very limited knowledge.

I would highly recommend you to go through this book which will clear your concepts as where, why and how SharePoint can be used in real life.

[Microsoft® SharePoint® 2010: Creating and Implementing Real-World Projects](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735662827)

Since answer to your question is too long to be answered here so I will just add links to tutorials you need,

> To build a knowledge library categorizing all our company procedures,
>   manuals, technical material, policies, etc.

[SharePoint 2010 - Creating a knowledge base part 1](http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2011/09/creating-knowledge-centre-with.html)

[SharePoint 2010 - Creating a knowledge base part 2](http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2011/09/creating-knowledge-centre-with_07.html)

[SharePoint 2010 - Creating a knowledge base part 3](http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2011/09/creating-knowledge-centre-with_26.html)

> Enable employees to write the above contents and publish them, so they
>   can be view, edited, updated, delete by specific users.

You need to create logins for your employees and give them [permissions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx).

> To have some workflows on certain documents, so that they will not be
>   available to employees until they went through predefined approval
>   steps.

[Getting started with SharePoint Server 2013 workflow](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj227177.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the links, actually i am not taking Sharepoint too easy. but i need to get started with it, i know i will not be able to cover all its features that why i searching for the features which is most related to implement my requirements at this stage. SECOND QUESTION are there relevant links for SP2013 to build knowledge base instead of SP2010.thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure they will work on SharePoint 2013 too.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in general how i will link the SP workflow with the Enterprise Wiki template.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is somewhat bigger in scope of a single specific answer, I have the following suggestions for you to get hold of "SharePoint" specific capabilities and being agnostic of what version of SharePoint you choose to use and co-relate them to your individual requirement.

> 1. To build a knowledge library categorizing all our company procedures,
>      manuals, technical material, policies, etc.

Cataloging , Taxonomy and Information Architecture are some areas where SharePoint provides rich capabilities through its Search and Managed Metadata services.  This should get you started regarding both 

[Configure Managed Metadata](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12713.sharepoint-2013-how-to-configure-managed-metadata-service.aspx) & 
[Configure Search](http://sharepointv15.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/sharepoint-2013-search-service-application-configuration/)

> Enable employees to write the above contents and publish them, so they
>   can be view, edited, updated, delete by specific users.

Understanding [SharePoint Publishing Infrastructure](http://www.sharepointchick.com/archive/2011/06/23/sharepoint-publishing-features-functionality.aspx) should address the second requirement.

> To have some workflows on certain documents, so that they will not be
>   available to employees until they went through predefined approval
>   steps.

And finally, along with publishing infrastructure , ECM features like drop-off library , retention policies,etc should get you through.

In a nutshell, theres whole lot of reading and doing involved to come up with a solution design for knowledge management in SharePoint. My suggestion is hire a good consultant if time is critical for the delivery of the initiative.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but why i should consider hiring a SharePoint consultant ? as in my case my company know that no one in our IT department have experience in SharePoint . so you mean that it will be difficult to build such an application by myself, after learning and reading related materials?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, if your organization is willing to spend the time for learning and adapting sharepoint in-house then its well and good. SharePoint has a intermediate to steep learning curve. Else, consultant is a suggested alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a link to my blog from this site :-) I recently got asked about a SP2013 knowledge base solution. Please read here:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/35fd81b0-2660-4cb6-bc84-f354eee49988

Comment: your link for developing wiki  in SP 2010 is great. but currently i am trying to achieve some extra requirement for my company wiki as i have mentioned in this link http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/509880a0-b91f-4032-a670-75821cf9b39d/#9c4723fa-ec67-4107-a02c-29c2b49f2191 . So can you help with these?